# The Jquery's document ready is not working in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 web application(a testing site).
I have a Product Controller , Product Views(Index(a non partial view) and Product.cshtml(a partial view)). I also have a _Layout(came from MVC)

Index.cshtml(*Not a partial view*)

```
@model IdentityASP.Models.ViewModel.ProductViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-unobstrusive-ajax")

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchProduct", "Product", null, new 
    AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }, null))
    {
    <input type="datetime" name="From" />
    <input type="datetime" name="To" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    }

    <div id="searchResults">@Html.Partial("~/Views/Product/Product.cshtml")
```

This renders ALL data in the beginning @Html.Partial("~/Views/Product/Product.cshtml")
When searching specific data this is also what is being used.

Product.cshtml (*Partial View*)

```
@model IdentityASP.Models.ViewModel.ProductViewModel
<div class="container">
    <table id="product-table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Id</th>
                <th>CategoryId</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>ManufacturerId</th>
                <th>ManufacturerName</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Released Date</th>
                <th>Released Year</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.CategoryId</td>
                    <td>@item.CategoryDescription</td>
                    <td>@item.ManufacturerId</td>
                    <td>@item.ManufacturerName</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.Model</td>
                    <td>@item.ReleasedDate</td>
                    <td>@item.ReleasedYear</td>
                    <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("EditProduct", "Product",new { id = item.Id })" data-target="#AddProductModal" class="btn-edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn-delete btn btn-info btn-default">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Script that are all located in  Index.cshtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {                                                     //  prepares datatable, highlight row selection , modal clear inputs on close.

            dataTable = $('#product-table').DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                "columnDefs": [
                {
                    className: "hide_column", "targets": [1],
                }
                ,
               {
                   className: "hide_column", "targets": [3]
               }]
       });


       $('#product-table tbody, .btn-edit, .btn-delete').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            dataTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });


       $("#AddProductModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
            clearInputs();
       });

       var categoryDescription = $("#categoryId option:selected").text();
       $("#categoryDescription").val(categoryDescription);

       var manufacturerName = $("#manufacturerId option:selected").text();
       $("#manufacturerName").val(manufacturerName);

    });

    function updateProductTable(e) {                                                    //  called function on ajax.beginform success
        //  set e.data to array
        //  if true updates table after add or edit, use row.add(array) or row().data(array) respectively.
        //  if false, validates input and show validation messages on each input box.

        var arr = null;
        var new_record = null;
        if (e.success) {


            if (e.success == "TrueAdd") {
                arr = $.map(e.data, function (value, index) { return [value]; });

                var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("EditProduct", "Product", new { id = "product" }))";
                url = url.replace('product', arr[0]);
                alert(arr[0]);
                new_record = [arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8],arr[9],
                    '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href=' + url + ' data-target="#AddProductModal" class="btn-edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>',
                    '<button type="button" class="btn-delete btn btn-info btn-default">Delete</button>'];
                dataTable.row.add(new_record).draw(false);
                clearInputs();
                hideModal();
            }


            else if (e.success == "TrueEdit") {
                arr = $.map(e.data, function (value, index) { return [value]; });

                var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("EditProduct", "Product", new { id = "product" }))";
                url = url.replace('product', arr[0]);

                new_record = [arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8],arr[9],
                    '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href=' + url + ' data-target="#AddProductModal" class="btn-edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>',
                    '<button type="button" class="btn-delete btn btn-info btn-default">Delete</button>'];

                dataTable.row('.selected').data(new_record).draw(false);
                clearInputs();
                hideModal();
            }

        }
        else if (!e.success) {
            $('.modal-body').find('input').each(function ()
            {
                if (!$(this).prop('required')) {}
                else {}
            });
        }

    }


    function hideModal() {
        $('#AddProductModal').modal('hide');                                            //  called function hide modal.
    }

    function clearInputs() {                                                            //  called function clear inputs , set productId to zero and categoryid to Select Category.
        $('.modal-body').find('input').val('');
        $('#productId').val('0');
        $('select#categoryId option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected');
        $('select#manufacturerId option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function () {                                  //  delete, open dialog box , get selected row data,  use jquery ajax to delete record, update table on success.

        var productId = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
        if (productId != 0) {
            if (confirm("Delete this record?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Product/Delete',
                    data: { productId: productId },
                    success: function (e) {
                        if (e.success) {
                            dataTable.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#categoryId', function () {                                    //  adds categoryId text to category description hidden field
        var categoryDescription = $("#categoryId option:selected").text();
        $("#categoryDescription").val(categoryDescription);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#manufacturerId', function () {                                //  adds manufacturerId text to manufacturer name hidden field
        var manufacturerName = $("#manufacturerId option:selected").text();
        $("#manufacturerName").val(manufacturerName);
    });


</script>
```

The question is , the document ready is working properly upon loading the Index and Partial View to display ALL list of data(You've got the searchbox, the highlights upon clicking each row).
but document ready is not working properly upon loading the Partial View after searching a specific data(using Index.cshtml AjaxBeginForm SearchProduct),You've got NO highlights after clicking each one and  no searchbox. I noticed all functions that are not under document ready are being called.

Why? , I will appreciate your responses

Thank you a lot
-John

Answer (score 1):

Its now working, I put the document ready script to Product.cshtml partial view and now the click and highlight are now working.

Thanks,
John